# Cant login to npm using termux on my mobile TERMUX__USER_ID: parameter not set

Tags: npm, termux

Iam trying to login to npm to publish a package but termux keep giving me `TERMUX__USER_ID: parameter not set` and cant open the browser.

I tried finding some info about this but sucsess.

here is the full error

```
npm adduser
npm WARN cli npm v10.2.5 does not support Node.js v18.16.1. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
npm notice Log in on https://registry.npmjs.org/
Create your account at:
https://www.npmjs.com/login?next=/login/cli/2817fb42-105d-4b44-b382-add884496c05
Press ENTER to open in the browser...
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c xdg-open 'https://www.npmjs.com/login?next=/login/cli/npm_***'
npm ERR! /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/xdg-open: 
43: TERMUX__USER_ID: parameter not set
```